# How to edit Order PDF in Magento 1.6.2

Tags: magento, pdf, magento-1.6

I learned how to edit Invoice PDF, Shipping PDF, Credit Memo PDF.
I was not able to find out where are the files responsabile of Order PDF, the one that downloads when you are in the order View page and press print.
Please, if anyone know, help me to find the files which are responsable for Order PDF.

Answer (score 0):

The transactional email responsible for the order, invoice, shipment etc. attachments can be located under the locale directory:

```
app/locale/{lang}/templates/email/sales/
```

Lang will be your default language, like en_US, en_GB etc.

The files responsible are:

- order_new.html
- order_new_guest.html

**Edit as per comments:**

I believe what you're looking for can be found over here:

```
app/design/frontend/{your_theme}/default/templates/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml
```

Please note though that changes you make here will also appear on the order view page.
To avoid this, you can use the following condition in this phtml (there is also an example in the original version):

```
<?php if ($this->getPrintStatus()): ?>
....        
<?php endif;?>
```

.. and for similar issues in the future: on the admin panel, in System/Configuration menu if you switch to "Store view", you will find an option under Advanced/Developer tab called "Template path hints". If you set it to "yes", you will see the template pathes in the frontend, embedded inline next to each block. [How to use template path hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I know how to edit and customize the emails which are sent automaticaly from Magento.

Comment: Sorry for unfinished comment from above.
Thank you for answering. I know how to edit and customize the emails which are sent automaticaly from Magento. My problem concern the Order PDF, the one that downloads when customer is in "My Orders" screen and press "Print Order".

Comment: Ah, I understand. As far as I am aware, Magento doesn't by default support an order PDF which is why it is not located in the same directory as the other files. Are you not maybe using a third party extension for this? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/email-attachments-by-fooman.html

Comment: No, I am not using any extension for this. I am using only a theme named Mhitech but I think that has no impact on Order PDF as long as in frontend, when a customer want to see his orders is looking to "my account" and after select the order which he want to see and in upper-right side are two buttons, one is "reorder" and second is "print order". When "print order" is pressed a tipical printing sceen appear where is seen the image of the order. This is what I want to edit.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think that may be the solution regarding the template path.

Comment: Accidentaly I succeed to discover which file I have to edit. It is /app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/template/sales/order/print.phtml. It took a lot of time for me to find it. Anyway thank you moose for all your time.

Comment: I did mention that about an hour ago :P You must have missed it.

Comment: Yes moose I missed it. Unfortunately the file /app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/template/sales/order/print.phtml is about the content of the Order and nothing about page format, font dimension, tables and all the other details. I shall look where this information is hiding. I can not move this discussion on chat as I have very low reputation.

Comment: Ah, unfortunately I am then also lost. I use Fooman's extension for PDF attachments, I really enjoy it. I've up-voted your question for originality :)

Comment: Came here from Google looking for the exact thing @Crist is. Did you find it in the end?